# HTML Submit Button not firing when form filled

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

I have a new login page which is not submitting. :(

If I click the button and the required fields are not entered, it fires me back the errors, but as soon as they're filled and I try to submit it does nothing.

The page is live at https://www.safewise.co.nz/trainwise/login

The code

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm" class="styled_form">
    <?php if(isset($redirectURL) && !empty($redirectURL)) { ?><input type="hidden" id="redirect" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $redirectURL; ?>" /><?php } ?>
    <div>
        <p id="login-title">Login</p>
        <input name="userEmail" type="email" class="validate[required]" id="userEmail" placeholder="Email"<?php if(isset($enteredEmail) && !empty($enteredEmail)){echo ' value="'.$enteredEmail.'"';} ?> required /><span class="form_hint">Email Address</span>
        <input name="userPwd" type="password" class="validate[required]" placeholder="Password" id="userPwd" required /><span class="form_hint">Password</span>
        <div class="login-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" style="vertical-align:middle;" /> <label for="remember">Remember Me</label></div>
        <p><input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin" value="Continue" class="form-button" /></p>
        <div id="forgot"><p><a href="javascript:alert('Coming Soon')">Register</a></p><p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="forgotPass">Forgotten Password?</a></p>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="forgotPass" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="modal-header"><h3>Forgot Password</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="forgotForm" id="forgotForm" >            
        <p style="margin-bottom:4px;"><em style="font-size:small;color:#3A3A3A">Enter your email address below to receive your new password.</em></p>
        <p><input name="rstEmail" type="text" class="validate[required]" id="rstEmail" placeholder="john@example.com" size="25" /> <input name="doReset" type="submit" id="doReset" value="Reset" class="form-button" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

The weird thing is as soon as I remove this code it works.

```
<div id="forgotPass" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="modal-header"><h3>Forgot Password</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="forgotForm" id="forgotForm" >            
        <p style="margin-bottom:4px;"><em style="font-size:small;color:#3A3A3A">Enter your email address below to receive your new password.</em></p>
        <p><input name="rstEmail" type="text" class="validate[required]" id="rstEmail" placeholder="john@example.com" size="25" /> <input name="doReset" type="submit" id="doReset" value="Reset" class="form-button" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I type `dfasds` and your form validates my email id

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I've updated this. It did check server side though. Thanks :)

Comment: Fixed! I was missing a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a closing div

```
<div id="forgot">
    <p><a href="javascript:alert('Coming Soon')">Register</a></p> 
    <p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="forgotPass">Forgotten Password?</a></p>
```

Needs a closing `div` at end

```
<div id="forgot">
    <p><a href="javascript:alert('Coming Soon')">Register</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="forgotPass">Forgotten Password?</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can accepted your own answer if it was the most suitable one.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr not until tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is that div located in the page? It is incorrect to have a form inside a form. And so your code may work when you remove the div above because you've taken out the second form.
Consider having them as two separate entities instead of nested.

Comment: After the first form. Not nested :)  I've updated my description above to show code

Answer (score 0):

Are these forms nested? You cannot have nested forms. You can have multiple forms in a page, just as long they're not nested.

Here's some ref on it http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

Comment: Certainly no nested forms. Already checked that. :). I've updated my description above to show code

Comment: You have a form inside another form. That is nested form. Move your </form> from the logForm form above the forgotPass div.

Comment: Sorry no it wasn't supposed to be. I hadn't closed a div properly.